# laravel Auth or token based api structure

Tags: laravel, api

i need help in laravel api i want to make api in laravel and  i am making api in laravel using **auth** . means i make api using simple auth without and token .i am just doing simple login and then maintain auth for api and web both side . so what  i have to do in this case . i am confuse in between **auth and token(through jwt)** based api **which is better and secure.** and which i have to work on.and for auth i am not generate any api token for dashboard apis.

Comment: For API I must prefer token-based API structure

Comment: okay Thanks. can i maintain Auth for token based api on server side  if yes then how i have to do it ?

Comment: I think you should use this laravel sanctum for authentication  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: okay i will chcek it